# Does contractibility imply contractibility with a basepoint?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a contractible space. If $x_0 \in X$, it is not necessarily true that the pointed space $(X,x_0)$ is contractible (i.e., it is possible that any contracting homotopy will move $x_0$).  An example is given in 1.4 of Spanier: the comb space.  However, this space is contractible as a pointed space if the basepoint is in the bottom line.

Is there a contractible space which is not contractible as a pointed space for *any* choice of basepoint?

My guess is that this will have to be some kind of pathological space, because for CW complexes, we have the [Whitehead theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem). (So I'm not completely sure that the Whitehead theorem is actually a statement about the *pointed* homotopy category, but hopefully I'm right.)

Comment: The variant of the Whitehead theorem given on page 346 of Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" shows you are right about no examples being CW-complexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  See exercise 7 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=tru-TWQFDAIC&lpg=PP1&dq=using%20the%20borsuk%20ulam%20theorem&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false).